# Where to start to create Jenkins gradle build with Pipeline Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I need to set up a Jenkins job which, on the face it, does a simple gradle build of some Java source.

However, as is often the case, the source is dependent upon a set of JAR files from a third-party, and there are different versions of these JARs that can be used going forward as a continuous integration process - hence Jenkins.

My source code has a build.gradle file whose content has a format partly determined by the third party, and changing it to my own style would be problematic. Here's an anonymous sample:

```
/* Module Build File */
apply from: "${System.getenv("third_party_home")}/etc/gradle/thirdParty.gradle"

ext {
name            = "myModule"
project.group   = "ProjectD"
project.version = "1.2.1"
}

dependencies {
compile "ThirdParty:jarNameA:4.2"
compile "ThirdParty:jarNameB:4.2"
compile "ThirdParty:jarNameC:4.0"
}
```

The issue is that, whilst the source code logically belongs in its own git repo, so does the third-party code included as part of the compilation -- and as controlled by the 'third_party_home' environment variable. So two git repos are needed here, but a simple Jenkins job does not support multiple interlinked repos like this.

Apparently, the best solution is to use the Jenkins Pipeline Plugin, but I'm aware it is complicated.

Could someone provide me with some simple pointers that explain how I go about configuring the plugin to achieve this sort of gradle build ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would really simplify things if you could achieve your entire goal within Gradle itself. I don't know Gradle well enough to say how that would work.

Alternatively, make use of an artifact repository server to deploy the third party code to. Then Jenkins and Gradle both have no need for separate repos to check out and compile.

Since you asked for a Jenkins solution, this is my suggestion:

Multiple repositories in a pipeline are, in fact, trivial. In a dir() closure, you can check out another repository.

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        third_party_home = "${WORKSPACE}/third_party_home"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                dir('third_party_home') {
                    git credentialsId: 'git-jenkins', url: 'git@git-server:third-party-repo'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            // run gradle here
        }
        // more stages
    }
}
```

You can use a single dir() with multiple checkouts or multiple dir() with a single checkout each.